# Android - How can i create a "black list" for the files of my application

Tags: android, file, blacklist

In my app i have many files (images and audio files). There is a way i can "mark" this files so that they cannot be read from other app like music player for the audio and gallery for the images? My question is: i can create a sort of "black list" that prevents to other app to see my files?

**EDIT**

As was recommended to me, i try making a ".nomedia" file into the folder that contains my files in this way:

```
File no_media_file = new File (my_path, "/.nomedia");
try {
     no_media_file.createNewFile();
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

the file ".nomedia" is created correctly (i verified using "ES File Explorer") but if i open "play music" app i can still play my audio file... Where am i doing wrong?

Comment: create empty `.nomedia`  in corresponding folder.

Comment: `In my app` Where is `in` exactly?

Comment: the files are stored in the memory of the device..

Comment: i try to create a ".nomedia" file in the folder where my files are locate but it seems not to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by inserting my files in a folder named like this: `".my_folder"` and it's worked!